# reloading a div after every 2 seconds with posting data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have created a jquery and I wanted to reload the file after every 2 seconds but also by posting data as well.

This is the html

```
<input type="hidden" id="class_id" value="<?php echo $data['class']; ?>" />
<input type="hidden" id="user_id" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['uid']; ?>" />
<tbody id="donors_list"></tbody>
```

My Jquery

```
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });

$(document).ready(function() {
    var class_id = $('#class_id').val();
    var user_id  = $('#user_id').val();
    setTimeout(
        $.ajax({
            url         : "includes/get_data.php", 
            type        : "POST",             
            data        : {class_id : class_id, user_id : user_id, new_list: 'new_list'},
            dataType    : 'text',            
            success     : function(data) {
                $("#donors_list").html(data);
            }
        });
    , 2000);
});
```

Error:

> VM229:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Comment: sorry did not posted error VM229:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) instead of `setTimeout`

> [**WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope.setInterval()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval)
>
> The `setInterval()` method of the WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope mixin repeatedly calls a function or executes a code snippet, with a fixed time delay between each call. Returns an `intervalID`.

```
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });

$(document).ready(function() {
    var class_id = $('#class_id').val();
    var user_id  = $('#user_id').val();

    setInterval(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url         : "includes/get_data.php", 
            type        : "POST",             
            data        : {class_id : class_id, user_id : user_id, new_list: 'new_list'},
            dataType    : 'text',            
            success     : function(data) {
                $("#donors_list").html(data);
            }
          });
      }, 2000);
});
```

Comment: @MarkAlan `setInterval` will create problem if api doesn't complete in 2sec

Comment: @Satpal You can always augment the interval, or work with Promises. But that was not the point of that question.

Comment: OP must know the pitfall of using a approach

Comment: @Satpal Indeed, thus your answer is a nice addition

Answer (score 1):

There is syntax error in the current code. the method `setTimeout()` expects a method/code in string literal to execute, neither is supplied.

As the interval is 2sec(very less), I would recommend you wrap the code in function, and then recursively call in the  `success` callback. Here `setTimeout` to used to defer the execution of `$.ajax()` call.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //on Page load
    f()
});

function f() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        var class_id = $('#class_id').val();
        var user_id = $('#user_id').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: "includes/get_data.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                class_id: class_id,
                user_id: user_id,
                new_list: 'new_list'
            },
            dataType: 'text',
            success: function (data) {
                $("#donors_list").html(data);

                //Schedule for next execution
                f();
            }
        })
    }, 2000);
}
```

Comment: I prefer this answer

Comment: @Satpal I prefer your approach too, didn't think about it, thanks, I just have one small question, in the success callback, when you call `f()`, will it respect the 2 second delay ? What will append if the ajax call make 1 second to complete, the next call will wait for more second ? And if the ajax call make 3 second to complete ? Will `f()` be called immediatly ?

Comment: @GilleQ. _will it respect the 2 second delay_ answer is No. If it takes more then 2sec to complete and we are firing it every 2 sec it will overload the server

Comment: @Satpal So after each success of the ajax call, `f()` will be called immediatly ? That doesn't meet OP requirement

Comment: @GilleQ., What if OP says 2millisecond?

Comment: Well, it's the OP requirement, not mineif he wants 2 millisecond, why not ? That's none of our business. We should just alert him that it could be problematic

Comment: _That's none of our business_ that's where our thought process are different. I have seen problems related to this scenario at SO

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134660/discussion-between-gille-q-and-satpal).